# Allowing rename but not moving to other directory

Tags: permissions, security, rename, ftp, vsftpd

Users can upload/delete/rename files via `vsftp` server and everything works well except they can also move files across directories.

Is it possible to allow renaming of files but disallow moving them around?

Example,

```
/ftp/work/xls/list.xls # can be deleted/renamed but should not moved to ie. 'doc'
/ftp/work/doc/list.doc # same thing, should not be moved elsewhere
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try playing with :

- cmds_allowed

  > This options specifies a comma separated list of allowed FTP commands (post login. USER, PASS and QUIT and others are always allowed pre-login). Other commands are rejected. This is a powerful method of really locking down an FTP server. Example: cmds_allowed=PASV,RETR,QUIT
  >   Default: (none)
- cmds_denied

  > This options specifies a comma separated list of denied FTP commands (post login. USER, PASS, QUIT and others are always allowed pre-login). If a command appears on both this and cmds_allowed then the denial takes precedence. (Added in v2.1.0).

and block the RNTO command for example.

Comment: this is interesting, but `RNTO` is also used when renaming plain files, not just when moving them around

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the unix model is to allow wrote to the directories you want, u.e. /home/mpapec and to disallow access un specific directories as desired.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `readlink` that supports the `-e` switch for path canonicalization, I suggest you prevent your users from using `mv` altogether and write your own `mv` as a replacement. Something like this perhaps:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ $# -ne 2 ] && echo "Only a two-argument mv is allowed" && exit 1

src="$1"
dst="$2"

srcdir="$(readlink -e "$(dirname "$src")")"
dstdir="$(readlink -e "$(dirname "$dst")")"

[ "$srcdir" != "$dstdir ] && echo "Cross-directory mv is forbidden" && exit 2
[ "$(basename "$src")" = "$(basename "$dst")" ] && echo "Source and destination are the same. Nothing to do." && exit 3

cp -p "$src" "$dst" && rm -f "$src"
```

Note that this will (obviously) cause the moved file's inode number to change unlike a regular `mv`.

Comment: is there a way to force `vsftp` to run external script before renaming?

Comment: @mpapec I wouldn't know. What I'm suggesting is to actually revoke execute rights to the original `mv` executable for `vsftp` users and force them to use this script instead (place it in their `PATH` somewhere before the original `mv`). Or better yet, jail `vsftp` users and make the original `mv` unavailable inside the jail.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure the directories which you want to move files to is enable  to +rw competence?

Have a try:

1. root mode
2. mount -o remount,rw dir      (dir is the directories which you want to move files to)

Comment: Actually, I believe the problem is the other way around: the users _can_ move the files to these other directories and the OP wants to revoke that permission.

Comment: @JosephR. that is correct